# Utilizando bibliotecas baixadas pelo Composer no Zend Framework 1

Tags: zend, composer

Qual a melhor forma de utilizar bibliotecas baixadas pelo Composer junto com o Zend Framework 1?

Vi no [seguinte link](http://wasil.org/zend-framework-1-and-composer), explicando como fazer este procedimento porém de uma forma que não parece ser muito correta.

Num comentário é falado de deixar a pasta vendor no *root* do projeto, e utilizar o autoloader do Zend.

Como utilizar o `autoloader` para este fim? Ou devo usar `require_once`?

Answer (score 1):

Quando você declara as dependências de um projeto por meio do `composer.json`, de alguma maneira você tem que incluir essas dependências no seu projeto. Suponhamos que o `composer.json` do seu projeto seja assim:

```
{
    "require": {
        "zendframework/zendframework1": "1.*"
    },
}
```

O composer, após instalar as dependências, cria um arquivo `vendor/autoload.php`, como você pode ver abaixo:

```
.
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
└── vendor
    ├── autoload.php
    ├── composer
    └── zendframework
```

Assim, seria apenas questão de criar um arquivo `index.php` na raiz (depende muito do seu projeto) e incluir as dependências da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
```

Faz algum tempo que não trabalho especificamente com projetos ZF1, mas se quiser posso ver para você.